# primefaces jsf 2 return empaty data

Tags: java, jsf-2, jdbc, primefaces

i have made jsf 2 webpage using primefaces 3.5 UI , so the webpage are worikng but my dataTable give empaty rows value , it should give me the values that's returned from database query .

note , i have tested the database query and it's working fine , but i think there is problem in sending this data to HTML beans .

my full code :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TableBean implements  Serializable  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public int model() throws ClassNotFoundException, ReflectiveOperationException, Exception{
    try {
        // i'm sure the following query return acutal data ! 

        Dbconnection NewConnect = new Dbconnection();
        Connection con = NewConnect.MakeConnect();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery(" select student_id , teacher_id , apssent_date , interval_id , Day_id from Apsent where class_id =  1" ) ;
        int StudentID  ;
        int ClassID  ;

    while(rs.next()){

         StudentID = rs.getInt(1);
         ClassID = rs.getInt(2);

         return StudentID ;    // or 0 or any value but the web page  still   give empaty rows value in data grid 

    }


}

    catch (SQLException e){

    }
    return 0000;


    }
```

my full html code :

```
<h:form>  
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean}">  
    <p:column headerText="Model">  
        <h:outputText value="#{model.StudentID}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Year">  
        <h:outputText value="#{model.StudentID}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Manufacturer">  
        <h:outputText value="#{model.StudentID}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Color">  
        <h:outputText value="#{model.StudentID}" />  
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. As I see you totally missunderstand implementation.
Your bean as a model should have private properties i.e.

```
private List<Object> list;
private int someInteger.
```

and public accessors to them i.e.:

```
public setList(List<Object> list){
   this.list = list;
}
public getList(){
   return list;
}
```

then you can add some code to get method like this:

```
public getSomeInteger(){
   return myObjectService.findAll(); //myObjectService.findAll() return result of some DB query.
}
```

then your xhtml datatable should look like:

```
<p:dataTable var="obj" value="#{yourBean.list}">  
    <p:column headerText="Model">  
        <h:outputText value="#{obj.property1}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Year">  
        <h:outputText value="#{obj.property2}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Manufacturer">  
        <h:outputText value="#{obj.property3}" />  
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>
```

For better understand JSF read some tutorials:
[Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/) or [BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.cz/)